# JavaScript implicit conversions in equality with a string

Tags: javascript, equality, implicit-conversion

How does JavaScript behave for the comparisons `true == "true"` and `(0 == "0")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type coercion aware operators (== and !=) can yield some wierd results:

```
'' == '0'          // false
0 == ''            // true
0 == '0'           // true

false == 'false'   // false
false == '0'       // true

false == undefined // false
false == null      // false
null == undefined  // true

' \t\r\n ' == 0    // true
```

The === and !== strict equality operators are always [preferred](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#equal).

Answer (score 3):

When using == or != if the types of the two expressions are different it will attempt to convert them to string, number, or Boolean etc

However you can use the identity comparison === or !== where no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.